# Session variable isnt returned

Tags: javascript, php

I got 2 php files.
I want to send $myusername from one page to another. I use $_SESSION in the first one, but it still doesn't appear on the second page.

**First page:**

```
<?php
  $username=$_POST["username"];
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count==1){
    header("location:the_cave.php");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  }
?>
```

**Second page:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $username=$_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

and then I want to use JS to put it into a span. but span remains empty.

```
document.getElementById("username").innerHTML="<?php echo $username;?>";
```

Comment: Does that `<span>` exist on the page at the time of you running that JS?

Comment: Look at the console in the browser. The error will tell you what the problem is. When you view the code in the page, do you see anything where the PHP is supposed to output? If not, it is a PHP issue and my guess, it is the header line...

Comment: yes, I just didn't put it here

Comment: Where in the document have you positioned the above JavaScript?

Comment: cant echo a php variable in JS.

Comment: console doesn't say anything

Comment: what do you mean oGeez?

Comment: so how can I print it using JS MammaWalter?

Comment: PHP variable doesn't exist client side. sure you need javascript ? you have to store your variable somewhere if you want to use it.

Comment: so can I write like var username="<?php echo $username=$_SESSION['username'];?>" and the use document.getElementById()?

Comment: @yamahamm I would rather have done this: `var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";`. Much shorter, and there's no need in naming the variable anyhing in the PHP bit, since you have a name for the variable in JS.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, guys, but nothing works...

Comment: @yamahamm Do you get any error whatsoever from either the php page or the js-code?

Comment: I get one error, but it isnt related with this part of code, i have had it like 2-3 months ago

Comment: @yamahamm let's try narrowing it down. Can you confirm the php code does what it should?

Comment: Yes, it is login-like page (page one) and it definitely works except this part of session

Comment: @yamahamm how about you use php to write out the username instead of JS, like this: `<span id="username"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></span>`?

Comment: @yamahamm glad I could help. Make sure to upvote and mark my answer as accepted! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *start* the php code on page one with:

```
session_start();
```

Thus, try this code on the first page:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  // all the other php code

  $username=$_POST["username"];
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['myusername'] = $username;
    header("location:the_cave.php");
    exit();
  }

?>
```

and to put the username into a span on the second page, just use this code:

```
<span id="username"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you started session in the first page using `session_start()` before putting values in session ?  if you did, try `echo $username=$_SESSION['username'];` in the second page before using javascript just to confirm you are getting the desired result.

Comment: try this <?php
  session_start();
  echo $username=$_POST["username"];
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count==1){
    header("location:the_cave.php");
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  }
?>
  <?php
  session_start();
  echo $username=$_SESSION['username'];
?>